# Words with Local plus Global Constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

While doing estimates on the complexity of an algorithm I have run into a word-combinatorial problem with both a local and a global constraint.

This seems to be a rather general situation and I'm sure there must be useful literature on the subject, though I haven't found anything that quite applies.

The local constraint in my case is simply a set of bad words to be avoided, and the global constraint is that no letter must repeated.

Consider an alphabet of $N$ letters divided in $p$ families. The $i$-th family contains $n_i$ letters ($i=1,...,p$), and $\sum_{i=1}^p n_i = N$.

We want to compute the number of words of $q$ letters ($q \leq N$) such that: 
(1) they all start with the same letter;
(2) no letter appears more than once;
(3) there are exactly $s$ pairs of adjacent letters from different families.

So the set of "bad" words consists of all two-letter words made with letters from two different families.

We are counting the self-avoiding words of length $q$ that begin with a given letter and contain exactly $s$ bad words as factors.

I can solve the local and global constraint separately. I solve the local one with the Goulden-Jackson method, the global one by just counting.

The problem is that Goulden-Jackson doesn't really apply to global constraints. If you apply it, the equation for the clusters is unyieldy. There must be a better way to handle these situations.

Comment: Linear or circular?

Comment: A linear string.

Comment: Now crossposted to math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1428618/264 In the future, please provide links to your other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Comment: I mean regular words.